# What type of server and hosting for magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, performance, hosting

I have this offer : https://www.ovh.com/fr/hebergement-web/offres-performance.xml ( Performance 1 ).

But I encounter quite a long time for the homepage of my site. What do you recommend ?

In my theme I have a css minify js extension what cela is it ?

How to optimize magento?

Answer (score 1):

Basically for The magento . its not needed specific hosting .
It just a web application.
But if you consider about to more user will come on site then you will have to pay more to the hosting company for the server performance like RAM,Processors..etc.
For the big business by magento you can take Dedicated servers , which can be manage by you or admin.

For the magento site optimization.

1. . Optimize images for that you can se mode_pagespeed or any image
   optimization extension.
2. . Compress your js and css by compressor extension many is free on
   magentocommerce
3. . enable Gzip in servers.

here you can check problem and recommendation for better speed.

http://gtmetrix.com/magento-optimization-guide.html

this is the guide for optimization.

http://www.gxjansen.com/101-ways-to-speed-up-your-magento-e-commerce-website/

Comment: mode_pagespeed is an extension?
How to enable Gzip in servers ?

Comment: mode_pagespeed is an extension?How to enable Gzip in servers ?

Comment: mode_pagespeed  is an package for apache from google...you have to install this in server.....and Gzip can be enable by htaccess